# flutter_bloc vs self written bloc or MVVM comparison

Tags: flutter, mvvm, architecture, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am grinding flutter architectures, and I was trying to compare self written MVVM(you can consider this as a self written bloc, where you are in full control of every aspect of an app), and flutter_bloc architectures, because they seem to be quite similar.

I have implemented the same screen using MVVM and bloc, and I really dislike the bloc's magic. I am worried that it may add additional bounds in a complex use cases. But yet it simplifies many things I had to overcome myself, with self written implementation, and was unable to find a clean solution.

I would really appreciate if you could share your production impression on MVVM vs Bloc vs flutter_bloc
architectures in flutter.
The advantages and downfalls of each approach.